# How to assign a view programmatically in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Let me explain my current scenario. I have a ViewController on storyboard as `CenterViewController`. On that view, I have the following properties-

```
@IBOutlet weak private var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var actualView: UIView!
```

I want to assign a view dynamically by program. For that I have a property i.e. -

```
@IBOutlet var actualView: UIView!
```

I have created a ViewController in storyboard. Now I need to assign the view that is related to that ViewController something like this-

```
let newView = ContactsViewController().view
actualView = newView
```

I know it will not work, but what else can I do for this purpose?

Comment: You should take a look at container views, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you :

```
let newView = ContactsViewController()
actualView = newView.view
```